# OpenID provider using Apache SSL/FakeBasicAuth?

Tags: ssl, authentication, single-sign-on, openid

I'd like to set up an OpenID provider for our group, which we can use to log in to internal and external OpenID-aware services (e.g. stackoverflow.com).

Our users all have X.509 certificates issued by our CA, so I think the ideal solution would use that to authenticate them (i.e. the provider shouldn't ask for a password). Maybe Apache FakeBasicAuth would work to extract the username from the SSL connection's certificate?

What would be the best software to use? Open Source preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got this working using:

- Apache with SSL
- [PHP OpenID Library](http://openidenabled.com/)

In the Apache configuration, I did this (note: didn't use FakeBasicAuth in the end):

> ```
> SSLCACertificateFile /.../myOrgCA.pem
> SSLVerifyClient require
> SSLVerifyDepth  1
> SSLOptions      +StdEnvVars
> ```

Edit action_default() to redirect the user to the https address if accessed over plain http. The plain http address is the one you publish in your `<link rel="openid.server">`.

Change getLoggedInUser() to extract the username from `$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email']`.

You can also edit doAuth() to provide the email address or full name in a similar way.

Note sure how secure this all is, but we use it for relatively low-value sites (forums, bug trackers, etc).

Comment: You *could* use HTTPS as your openid.server address; some providers like Yahoo and Google do.  The potential downside is that HTTPS fetching support on relying parties is remarkably flaky.  They don't have the right crypto libs, or they don't have the root CA certs accessible, or they don't have clear policy about what to do with invalid certs...

But many RPs do work fine that way (hopefully Yahoo is forcing that number up), and it reduces a potentially vulnerable redirect, so consider it.

Answer (score 0):

I've considered the same thing myself, and the best answer I could find after some research was exactly as you suggested – Apache running mod_ssl, FakeBasicAuth to ID the user, and then extract that to identify the user and validate them.